# Android change items in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, textview, navigation-drawer

I want to change the text style of the 6 items from my Navigation Drawer Layout. So I tried it with:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    TextView tx = (TextView) mDrawerList.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null).findViewById(R.id.title);
    tx.setTypeface(semibold);
    tx.setTextSize(20);
}
```

but nothing changed.
As in my onItemClick method I get the View of the item, so it's easily to do it there like:

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_title);
        tv.setTypeface(semibold);
        tv.setTextSize(20);
    }
```

How can I change the style of an item outside of the onItemClick method, how can I reference the view of the item?

EDIT:
After change getView to getChildAt I'm getting this exception

```
02-12 20:16:51.736    8133-8133/example.de.example E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: example.de.example, PID: 8133
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{example.de.example/example.de.example.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at example.de.example.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:155)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What layout are your list items ? do you use any style ? I Think you are looking for [Selectors](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_3_-_customizing_a_listview%27s_appearance/)

Comment: My list items are inside a RelativeLayout, don't use any style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These calls you make to `getView` creates new views that are never actually used by your `ListView`.

You need to fetch the views through your `ListView`, not through it's adapter:

```
mDrawerList.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Loop all children and set the TextView's typeface
        for(int i=0; i<mDrawerList.getChildCount(); i++){
            View child = mDrawerList.getChildAt(i);
            TextView tx = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.title);
            if (tx == null) {
                Log.e("TAG", "TextView at " + i + " not found!");
                continue;
            }
            tx.setTypeface(semibold);
            tx.setTextSize(20);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: now I'm getting a NullPointerException. I updated my question

Comment: @RyuZz what's on MainActivity.java line 155?

Comment: "TextView tx = (TextView) mDrawerList.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.title);"
it's in onCreate

Comment: @RyuZz see my updated answer, that might fix it. It doesn't make much sense to have children count > 0 but when fetching the child to receive null.